# test for first row when using mysql_fetch_assoc

Tags: php

I have the following query

```
<?php
  $query = "SELECT * FROM mytable";
  $result = mysql_query($query);
?>



<?php while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) { ?>


if first row, add  id = "thumb1"

<a id="thumb1" href='address' onclick="...">
<img src='<?php echo 'Index_Images/image_thumb_' . $row['IMG_IDENTIFIER'] . '.jpg'; ?>' />
</a>   


<?php else ?>

<a id="others" href='address' onclick="...">
<img src='<?php echo 'Index_Images/image_thumb_' . $row['IMG_IDENTIFIER'] . '.jpg'; ?>' />
</a>  

<?php
}
?>
```

I want to know how to test for the first row in `mysql_fetch_assoc`, if that is possible.

Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use variable `$i`, which is incremented in each loop.

```
$i = 0;

while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    if ($i == 0) {
        echo 'first row';
    }

    echo ...;

    $i++;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Try:

```
// ...
$first = true;
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
   if ($first) {
     // code with thumb1
   } else {
     // code with others
   }
   $first = false;
} 
// ...
```

or even better when it comes to the complexity of code:

```
// ...
$first = true;
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
   if ($first) {
     // code with thumb1
     $first = false;
     continue;
   }
   // code with others
} 
// ...
```

Also I would consider using [PDO](http://wiki.hashphp.org/PDO_Tutorial_for_MySQL_Developers) or mysqli or some ORM instead of mysql.

If you will put params into query in future remember of escaping - not esacping is one of the most common ways to have sql injection vulnerability with mysql in php.

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php
  $query = "SELECT * FROM mytable";
  $result = mysql_query($query);
  $i = 1;
?>



<?php while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) { ?>

<?php if($i == 1) {
if first row, add  id = "thumb1"

<a id="thumb1" href='address' onclick="...">
<img src='<?php echo 'Index_Images/image_thumb_' . $row['IMG_IDENTIFIER'] . '.jpg'; ?>' />
</a>   


<?php }else{ ?>

<a id="others" href='address' onclick="...">
<img src='<?php echo 'Index_Images/image_thumb_' . $row['IMG_IDENTIFIER'] . '.jpg'; ?>' />
</a>  

<?php
}
$i++;
}
?>
```

Check this, if it works.